# Error in the nginx error log, and what to do about it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have the following error in my nginx logs:

> 2014/09/23 01:56:40 [info] 18250#0: *38 epoll_wait() reported that
>   client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed
>   too while sending request to upstream, client: 49.128.46.126, server:
>   tm-google-dev.gumi.sg, request: "GET /versions/ping HTTP/1.1",
>   upstream: "passenger:/tmp/passenger.1.0.18229/generation-0/request:",
>   host: "tm-google-dev.gumi.sg:443"

It is not exactly an error 500 or 403, so i can't make out what is it trying to say. Please help. Thanks. The app is a rails app.

Comment: I would try increasing the timeout values. If it doesn't help, enable nginx debug to check the debug logs.

Comment: It means that client browser dropped connection for some reason. It's OK to have a few of such records, but if you have a lot of them it worth to look at performance of your backend.